Spring reactive WebClient cancel ongoing request on flux error
I have a streaming service that relays the client request to an external service using WebClient, returning the Flux from the external service to the client.
When the client disconnects from my service, I want to disconnect WebClient from the external service too. How can I achieve this?
So far I've found that when the client disconnects, I get a broken pipe IOException, which I can catch and execute a callback on using flux.doOnError(IOException.class, e -> {}, but I don't know what to put in the callback to cancel the ongoing request.
What I've tried
I found a GeeksForGeeks guide on cancelloing ongoing flux from WebClient and implemented it like this:
Flux<String> flux = webClient.post()
    .uri(uri)
    .bodyValue(req)
    .retrieve()
    .bodyToFlux(String.class)
    // some filters and maps
    ;
Disposable disposable = flux.subscribe();
return flux.doOnError(IOException.class, e -> disposable.dispose());

but it did not work. For testing, I've also tried just calling .dispose() right away and kept my client connected:
Flux<String> flux = webClient.post()
    .uri(uri)
    .bodyValue(req)
    .retrieve()
    .bodyToFlux(String.class)
    // some filters and maps
    ;
Disposable disposable = flux.subscribe();
disposable.dispose();
log.info("is disposed: {}", disposable.isDisposed());
return flux;

and the log showed true but the client continued receiving data.
Stack trace
Exception in thread "task-8" java.lang.IllegalStateException: A non-container (application) thread attempted to use the AsyncContext after an error had occurred and the call to AsyncListener.onError() had returned. This is not allowed to avoid race conditions.
        at org.apache.catalina.core.AsyncContextImpl.check(AsyncContextImpl.java:537)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.AsyncContextImpl.dispatch(AsyncContextImpl.java:152)
        at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.HttpServlet3RequestFactory$SecurityContextAsyncContext.dispatch(HttpServlet3RequestFactory.java:316)
        at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.HttpServlet3RequestFactory$SecurityContextAsyncContext.dispatch(HttpServlet3RequestFactory.java:316)
        at org.springframework.web.context.request.async.StandardServletAsyncWebRequest.dispatch(StandardServletAsyncWebRequest.java:170)
        at org.springframework.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManager.setConcurrentResultAndDispatch(WebAsyncManager.java:411)
        at org.springframework.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManager.lambda$startDeferredResultProcessing$8(WebAsyncManager.java:489)
        at org.springframework.web.context.request.async.DeferredResult.setResultInternal(DeferredResult.java:272)
        at org.springframework.web.context.request.async.DeferredResult.setErrorResult(DeferredResult.java:287)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ResponseBodyEmitterReturnValueHandler$HttpMessageConvertingHandler.completeWithError(ResponseBodyEmitterReturnValueHandler.java:241)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ResponseBodyEmitter.completeWithError(ResponseBodyEmitter.java:267)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ReactiveTypeHandler$AbstractEmitterSubscriber.run(ReactiveTypeHandler.java:340)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1144)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:642)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)
2025/01/02 08:29:06.787 ERROR [http-nio-8080-exec-3] com.my.project.name.exception.RestExceptionHandler.getResponse [RestExceptionHandler.java:118]: ServletOutputStream failed to flush: ServletOutputStream failed to flush: java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
org.springframework.web.context.request.async.AsyncRequestNotUsableException: ServletOutputStream failed to flush: ServletOutputStream failed to flush: java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
        at org.springframework.web.context.request.async.StandardServletAsyncWebRequest$LifecycleHttpServletResponse.handleIOException(StandardServletAsyncWebRequest.java:343)
        at org.springframework.web.context.request.async.StandardServletAsyncWebRequest$LifecycleServletOutputStream.flush(StandardServletAsyncWebRequest.java:415)
        at org.springframework.util.StreamUtils.copy(StreamUtils.java:135)
        at org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(StringHttpMessageConverter.java:128)
        at org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(StringHttpMessageConverter.java:44)
        at org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractHttpMessageConverter.write(AbstractHttpMessageConverter.java:235)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ResponseBodyEmitterReturnValueHandler$HttpMessageConvertingHandler.sendInternal(ResponseBodyEmitterReturnValueHandler.java:221)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ResponseBodyEmitterReturnValueHandler$HttpMessageConvertingHandler.send(ResponseBodyEmitterReturnValueHandler.java:212)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ResponseBodyEmitter.sendInternal(ResponseBodyEmitter.java:223)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ResponseBodyEmitter.send(ResponseBodyEmitter.java:214)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.SseEmitter.send(SseEmitter.java:135)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.SseEmitter.send(SseEmitter.java:118)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ReactiveTypeHandler$SseEmitterSubscriber.send(ReactiveTypeHandler.java:392)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ReactiveTypeHandler$AbstractEmitterSubscriber.run(ReactiveTypeHandler.java:332)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1144)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:642)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)
Caused by: org.springframework.web.context.request.async.AsyncRequestNotUsableException: ServletOutputStream failed to flush: java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
        at org.springframework.web.context.request.async.StandardServletAsyncWebRequest$LifecycleHttpServletResponse.handleIOException(StandardServletAsyncWebRequest.java:343)
        at org.springframework.web.context.request.async.StandardServletAsyncWebRequest$LifecycleServletOutputStream.flush(StandardServletAsyncWebRequest.java:415)
        at org.springframework.web.context.request.async.StandardServletAsyncWebRequest$LifecycleServletOutputStream.flush(StandardServletAsyncWebRequest.java:412)
        ... 15 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.connector.ClientAbortException: java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.doFlush(OutputBuffer.java:303)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.flush(OutputBuffer.java:265)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteOutputStream.flush(CoyoteOutputStream.java:136)
        at org.springframework.security.web.util.OnCommittedResponseWrapper$SaveContextServletOutputStream.flush(OnCommittedResponseWrapper.java:524)
        at org.springframework.web.context.request.async.StandardServletAsyncWebRequest$LifecycleServletOutputStream.flush(StandardServletAsyncWebRequest.java:412)
        ... 16 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write0(Native Method)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:62)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:137)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:102)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:58)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:542)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioChannel.write(NioChannel.java:122)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper.doWrite(NioEndpoint.java:1378)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapperBase.doWrite(SocketWrapperBase.java:764)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapperBase.flushBlocking(SocketWrapperBase.java:728)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapperBase.flush(SocketWrapperBase.java:712)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11OutputBuffer$SocketOutputBuffer.flush(Http11OutputBuffer.java:574)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.filters.ChunkedOutputFilter.flush(ChunkedOutputFilter.java:156)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11OutputBuffer.flush(Http11OutputBuffer.java:216)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.flush(Http11Processor.java:1252)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessor.action(AbstractProcessor.java:408)
        at org.apache.coyote.Response.action(Response.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.doFlush(OutputBuffer.java:299)
        ... 20 common frames omitted
2025/01/02 08:29:06.803 WARN [http-nio-8080-exec-3] org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver.logException [AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver.java:247]: Resolved [org.springframework.web.context.request.async.AsyncRequestNotUsableException: ServletOutputStream failed to flush: ServletOutputStream failed to flush: java.io.IOException: Broken pipe]


Please add a code sample how your service calls external service and a example of exception stack trace. As far as I understand, the exception should be thrown in your service and not in WebClient call.
